# OS X 10.5 Leopard (G5) can read/reformat disk, but says it's full when I try to copy to it

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, osx-leopard, disk-utility

I've got an old 2005 G5 cheese grater tower that was my former media center.  I pulled it out of storage today to try and retrieve backups of a couple of items I'd misplaced, and am having a bit of an issue with moving the data.

My usual USB drives that I use are Seagate Backup Plus Portables, in MS-DOS/FAT-32 format.  I'm pretty sure I'd gotten it to copy to one such drive before I moved, but I can't say that with absolute certainty.  What I do know is that when I tried it this time, I was getting the following:

- Disk size: -- (both I tested with were 1TB)
- Used: --
- Available Space: Zero bytes

Trying to copy anything to it naturally fails, due to the Zero bytes available.  I tried connecting a drive I knew had material on it, and it could show/read the files, but still wouldn't allow me to copy over anything.  Opening Disk Utility, it tried to say that S.M.A.R.T. detected a fatal error, however Sierra's disk utility gives the same drive a clean bill of health.

Since the Seagates run on USB 3.0, I decided to eliminate that variable and plugged in a standard, no-name 8GB USB 2.0 thumb drive I had lying around.  It's behaving the same way, just without the threat of impending drive failure.  Leopard's Disk Utility was able to detect the drive and its proper size, so I tried having Leopard erase the drive and reformat it as FAT-32.  After the formatting, Disk Utility was still perfectly aware of what it was and its state, but Finder still insists that it's a drive with an unknown size and Zero kb available.

Does this sound like a hardware failure, software failure, or a little bit of both?

Comment: MBR or GPT? Truly FAT32, or exFAT?

Comment: Pretty certain it's MBR; used the FAT32 setting from Disk Utility when formatting.  Haven't had any good experiences with exFat, so I always use the basic MS-DOS (FAT32) setting.